# Facebook PHP API : delete a notification previously sent by my app

Tags: php, facebook, api, notifications

I'm sending notifications to my application users like this :

```
require_once('php-sdk/facebook.php');
$config = array
(
    'appId' => 'blabla',
    'secret' => 'blablablabla',
);
$facebook = new Facebook($config);
$user_id = $facebook->getUser();
$post = $facebook->api('/'.$user_id.'/notifications/', 'post',  array
    (
        'access_token' => 'blabla|blablablabla',
        'href' => 'https://www.my_app_url.net/',
        'template' => "You have X new updates waiting on MyAppName !",
        'ref' => 'MyApp_notification'
    ));
```

Now, if the user have a new update on my app but haven't visited since last notification, I send him a new notification with the new number of updates waiting for him, which could be very annoying if he doesn't connect for a while and has 50 new facebook notifications...

So my question is : **Is it possible to remove previous notification(s) on user's Facebook when I send a new one using the PHP API ?**

I've searched but couldn't find the answer...

Comment: You're right Arthur, notification "deletion" is a kind of nonsense ...
`;)` Let me google that for you  => [Answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147531/how-mark-my-question-as-answered-on-stackoverflow)

Comment: I'd read some posts that said it is possible to delete objets with the following method :
`$facebook->api('/OBJECT_ID', 'DELETE');`
But it seems that a notification isn't considered as a deletable object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I have found how to mark notifications as read.**

```
require_once('php-sdk/facebook.php');
$config = array
(
    'appId' => 'blabla',
    'secret' => 'blablablabla',
);
$facebook = new Facebook($config);
$user_id = $facebook->getUser();
if ($user_id) // Only if the user is connected
{
    $permissions = $facebook->api("/me/permissions");
    if (array_key_exists('manage_notifications', $permissions['data'][0])) // Check if we have the permission to manage the notifications
    {
        $access_token = $facebook->getAccessToken();
        $get = $facebook->api('/me/notifications?include_read=0&access_token='.$access_token, 'get'); // We get all the unread notifications from the app
        for ($i=0; $i&lt;count($get['data']); $i++) // Now let's mark each of them as read
        {
            $notification_id = $get['data'][$i]['id'];
            $facebook->api('/'.$notification_id.'?unread=0&access_token='.$access_token, 'post');
            echo 'Mark '.$notification_id.' as read : OK&lt;br>';
        }
    }
    else
    {
        echo 'err0r: user have not allowed the app to manage his notifications';
    }
}
else
{
    echo 'err0r: no user connected to the app';
}
```

It seems that there is no way to DELETE some notifications, so this is the best solution I have found... hope this will help anyone who have the same problem !

Here's a link to the full code on my PasteBin : http://pastebin.com/2J0c5L18